# Django: Many to Many Relationship puts all object in model in another object

Tags: django, sqlite

I am trying to have it so I can select which clusters I select for each Issue. However, it auto adds all of them, why is that?

Here is what is happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CZRY.png
Here is the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsKX9.png

Comment: can you add the models definition that you have in your models.py file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't think it automatically adds all because you have to press ctrl and click on the clusters you want to select I think.

Comment: I can't get it so save my choices though.

Comment: Hold down control and click on the clusters you want to choose then you can save your choices